# SSIS "merge join -> conditional split -> Insert/Update" vs "separating Insert and update in two Data flows"?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm creating a package to sync a table using some columns from another table. The majority of the actions will be inserting. Which one is faster in SSIS?

1. merge join -> conditional split -> Insert/Update
2. create two separated data flows for insert and update respectively.